# Percentage of black pixels for a cell array of images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've split an image up into pieces and stored them in a cell array using `mat2cell()`. I want to calculate the percentage of black pixels in each of the cells. What is the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you know how to do it for each cell?

Answer (score 5):

You could either loop through each element, and count the number of black pixels (sum the pixels == 0) and divide by the total number of pixels in that cell.

```
for k = 1:numel(CA)
    % Number of black pixels (For RGB ensures all channels are 0)
    nBlack = sum(sum(all(CA{k} == 0, 3));

    % Total number of pixels divided by 3rd dimension (RGB-compatible)
    nPixels = numel(CA{k}) / size(CA{k}, 3);

    percentBlack(k) = nBlack / nPixels;
end
```

Or you can use `cellfun` to do some of this looping for you.

```
percentBlack = cellfun(@(x)sum(sum(all(x == 0, 3))) / (numel(x) / size(x,3)), CA);
```

And the output will be the same size as `CA`.

> Just a note on the `sum(sum(all(x == 0, 3)))` idiom. Essentially we create a logical matrix (the size of `x`) that is 1 where `x(k) == 0` and 0 everywhere else. In the case of an RGB image, we will want to check that *all* channels (3rd dimension) are 0 (`all(x == 0, 3)`). Then by summing all elements in this logical array (`sum(sum(`), we are in effect *counting* the number of black pixels.

Comment: @Suever, thanks, that is very helpful, one further question, how could I put this number in the caption of the sub image. I've posted my code so far that displays each image with a caption.

Comment: @user6029533 That is a different question that should be asked in a different thread. Although, first take a second and think about how you could convert a number to a string and then set that to the caption. I bet you can figure it out on your own!

Comment: @user6029533 Maybe something like this? `caption = sprintf('Frame #%d of %d; %% Black = %0.2f', plotIndex, numPlotsR*numPlotsC, avgBlack * 100);`

Comment: @Suever, thanks, I was trying something like but because I'm displaying the images inside a loop, I'm not sure how to grab the relevant percentage value. I've posted the code in the original post.

Comment: @user6029533 well you have an array of percentages that you can index into within your for loop `percentBlack(k)`